# When to use “rencontrer” and “se rencontrer”?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes-pronominaux

My dictionary translates both as - "to meet."

I'm wondering, however, if there is not at least some difference in meaning between the two that would dictate when to use one instead of the other?

Comment: If you analyze the latter as "get together", it may help.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Don't you mean the difference between the **reflexive** and regular use ? Do you actually mean **pronominal**, that is: irrespective of the pronoun being used ?

Comment: @aCOSwt Peut-être ma formulation ou ma maîtrise du langage grammatical est-elle insuffisante. Toute tentative d'explication rationnelle, assez complète, et SIMPLE conviendra. Désolé du flou et merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Se* is a *“reflexive pronoun”* used with a *“pronomial verb”*.

I think the distinction is clearest in the first person plural:

> *Nous **nous** rencontrons* -- We meet **each other** (or “meet ourselves”)
>
> *Nous <strike>nous</strike> rencontrons quelqu'un d'autre* -- We meet someone else

Comment: However, you can never say "We meet ourselves";  would that have  recently been introduced into English?

Comment: @user168676 No you're right, you'd never say that in English -- I added it in "scare quotes" as a literal translation not an idiomatic translation.

Comment: Got it! I wasn't aware of that use of quotes, scare quotes, you say.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that there isn't a difference stated between the forms of the verb. But from what I can gather from the examples in my own dictionaries you can see that *“rencontrer”* might actually be used for a meaning closer to *“happen to meet someone”*, *“stumble across”* and so on - let's call it a random meeting. And for *“se rencontrer"* I believe the usage is for planned actions.

I do not insist on this being the only meaning of *“rencontrer”*, this is just what I found in my books. Hope it was helpful :)

Comment: What do you mean by "there isn't a difference stated between the forms of the verb"? If you would rephrase that in somewhat more idiomatic way we could get straight at what you want to say. You might also bring a correction to your last contention: it is not true: not only for planned actions but as well for chance happening; example: Nous nous sommes rencontrés alors que nous marchions le long de la Volga ; je l'ai prise pour quelqu'un d'autre, mais depuis nous sommes amies.

Answer (score 2):

Désolé, je ne vois pas de différence de sens : hier, j'ai rencontré ma cousine, plus précisément nous nous sommes rencontrés à la gare, au guichet où je venais de prendre mon billet et où elle rencontrait des difficultés à se faire rembourser le sien.

Je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse de voie pronominale stricto sensu, comme dans « se raser » ou « se cacher », donc en anglais l'idée serait “each other” et non “themselves”.

On remarquera au passage que l'anglais, langue métisse, dispose à la fois de la racine française (encounter) et de la racine germanique (meet).

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse. Il me semble qu'elle ne couvre pas l'ensemble des possibilités, mais c'est un début. Peut-être n'y a-t-il pas une différence énorme. Peut-être simplement une idée de mutualité de la rencontre si «nous nous rencontrons», alors que s'il s'agit d'une espèce d'énergumène, la rencontre n'est marquante que pour moi (l’énergumène m'a rencontré aussi, mais je ne compte pas dans sa journée, alors que sa prestation grotesque peut avoir été un moment marquant pour moi).

Comment: @Montée de lait – je serais ravi de prendre connaissance de « l'ensemble des possibilités » car présentement je n'en discerne pas d'autres. Sur votre exemple, je ne vois toujours pas le problème : j'ai rencontré un énergumène qui ne m'a même pas vu tant il […], et le lendemain cet énergumène et moi nous nous sommes de nouveau rencontrés, plus exactement il m'est rentré dedans et en tant qu'énergumène il ne s'est même pas excusé   ;–)

Comment: Que puis-je ajouter? Si vous ne voyez pas d'autres possibilités, laissons donc d'autres personnes voir si elles le peuvent... (un autre ne disait-il pas *«[J’existe, je me suis rencontré](https://www.babelio.com/livres/Gotlib-Jexiste-je-me-suis-rencontre/77361)»*?, que je ne songerais pas à reformuler «J’ai rencontré moi-même»).

Comment: @Montée de lait – ah, là, c'est une parodie de ce mauvais esprit de Gotlib, cela se réfère bien sûr à « Dieu existe, je L'ai rencontré » d'André Frossard ; comme c'est une parodie, un calque conçu pour se moquer tout en mettant les rieurs de son côté, on ne peut en tirer quoi que ce soit quant à la grammaire … Mais dans le sens, c'est bien « j'ai rencontré moi-même », non réflexif. Bon courage pour votre quête, et qu'elle ne rapporte pas des scories comme un certain nombre figurent déjà dans cette page     ;–/

Comment: Merci encore. Le sens est bien celui-là, mais ce ne sera pas la forme à utiliser pour ce cas. De nouveau, je vous dis apprécier votre réponse. La première qui commence à me parler.

Answer (score 0):

Nous nous sommes rencontré un beau matin d'été. Mes parents se sont rencontré aussi comme cela.

Nous rencontrons des difficultés extrême dans l'élaboration de ce projet.

Comment: Emploi de auxiliaire être dans la forme du verbe ici, donc accord au pluriel: _rencontrés_. Accord de l'adjectif en genre et nombre(nbre requis ici): _extrêmes_.

Answer (score 0):

Rencontrer = encounter, come across

Se = one's self (singular), each other (plural)

So it's the same as in English: to encounter someone (rencontrer quelqu'un), or to encounter one another (se rencontrer). The difference is that 'meet' implies it's you and other people meeting each other, so you don't necessarily need to add that you're part of that event. While the most accurate translation is 'encounter', because it also applies to encountering objects. So in the case of encountering persons, you have to distinguish between encountering someone as in passing them on the street (or deliberately going to meet someone)... and encountering someone as in meeting up with them, coming together (read: whether you're part of that group). When a group of people meet, they are encountering themselves, sotospeak.

And that 'se' is conjugated depending on who it is that meets, who it is that encounters theirselves:
nous nous rencontrons,
vous vous rencontrez,
ils/elles se rencontrent.

It's just the same as in English, so also in the figurative sense of meeting one's self, comming across one's limits: 
Sur le Mont Ventoux, je me rencontrais.
...tu te rencontrais.
...il se rencontrait.
...nous nous rencontrions.
...vous vous rencontriez.
...ils/elles se rencontraient.

And the difference between the two really gets shown with the use of 'with': "Je me rencontre avec mes amis." (I meet with my friends.) Because if you meet **with** someone, you're coming together, and as such you're part of the people that are met (in French). So you say you're encountering/coming across yourself being together with your friends, sotospeak.

Comment: Les formes « je/tu/il/ me/te/se rencontrais/rencontrait » ne sont pas utilisées; cela se comprend assez bien, puisque pour une action mutuelle il faut au moins deux personnes; donc un singulier n'est pas possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "rencontrer" means meeting in general, and the meeting itself is our point, but "se rencontrer" means meeting, while people are our point. In fact, when we use "se rencontrer" we want to say that those people know each other and they are not strangers.

Answer (score 0):

Très souvent, l'emploi de "se rencontrer" implique quelque chose de plus fort qu'une simple réunion. Une découverte, un amour, une amitié .... Ou la condition nécessaire pour résoudre un problème, trouver une solution. Le plus souvent cela implique une conséquence positive, ou la volonté initiale que ce soit le cas. De plus en général cela concerne un nombre limité de personnes, souvent deux.